# How to show the row info of listview in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list view on c# but what i want is when i select a row it should show the column 1 value of that row on message box

```
private void CreateMyListView()
        {
            // Create a new ListView control.
            //ListView listView1 = new ListView();
            //listView1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), new Size(300, 200));

            // Set the view to show details.
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            // Allow the user to edit item text.
            listView1.LabelEdit = true;
            // Allow the user to rearrange columns.
            listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
            // Display check boxes.
            listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
            // Select the item and subitems when selection is made.
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
            // Display grid lines.
            listView1.GridLines = true;
            // Sort the items in the list in ascending order.
            listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

            // Create three items and three sets of subitems for each item.
            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("item1", 0);
            // Place a check mark next to the item.
            item1.Checked = true;
            item1.SubItems.Add("1");
            item1.SubItems.Add("2");
            item1.SubItems.Add("3");
            ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("item2", 1);
            item2.SubItems.Add("4");
            item2.SubItems.Add("5");
            item2.SubItems.Add("6");
            ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("item3", 0);
            // Place a check mark next to the item.
            item3.Checked = true;
            item3.SubItems.Add("7");
            item3.SubItems.Add("8");
            item3.SubItems.Add("9");

            // Create columns for the items and subitems.
            // Width of -2 indicates auto-size.
            listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Column 2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Column 3", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Column 4", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Center);

            //Add the items to the ListView.
            listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1, item2, item3 });

            // Create two ImageList objects.
            ImageList imageListSmall = new ImageList();
            ImageList imageListLarge = new ImageList();
            // Initialize the ImageList objects with bitmaps.
            //imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MySmallImage1.bmp"));
            //imageListSmall.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MySmallImage2.bmp"));
            //imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MyLargeImage1.bmp"));
            //imageListLarge.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\MyLargeImage2.bmp"));

            //Assign the ImageList objects to the ListView.
            listView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge;
            listView1.SmallImageList = imageListSmall;

            // Add the ListView to the control collection.
            this.Controls.Add(listView1);
        }
```

So is there any thing which can help me to show the column 1 value for that row from the listview?

Comment: When you click an item in a listview you trigger the selectedindexchanged event. Inside this event you could get the focuseditem's .Text property. `MessageBox.Show(listView1.FocusedItem.Text)` This can also be used for any other column by using FocusedItem.Subitem(_index_).Text

Comment: its working but there is a problem its showing the previous one first then the next one

Comment: Update your post to show the code and the event you're using. I can't reproduce based off of my instructions. EDIT: Actually, I can reproduce this with the checkboxes, I missed where you had them enabled.

Comment: ok thanks for that

Comment: So, it appears that it has nothing to do with the settings and the by design the event is being called at the start of the selectionchange and when it finishes. This is why you see the previous selection and the current selection on the second click of the listview. If you were to set a label's text to the focuseditem.text it would happen so fast that it would appear to only show the current item. The messagebox is stopping the thread with each call so that is why you're seeing both calls to the event.